# RestTemplate and UriComponentsBuilder to access API

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

i am trying to access the contents of an API having a query parameter represented as JSON and I need to send a URL using RestTemplate and UriComponentsBuilder

the api:
http://remote-api/person?filter={"code":"30ABD999"}&page=0&size=1&sort=name

```
 public Person getPerson(String filter, Optional<Integer> size, 
                         Optional<Integer> page, Optional<String> sort){

        String endpoint= "http://localhost:8081/person"

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(this.endpoint)
                .queryParam("filter",filter);

        page.ifPresent(p -> builder.queryParam("page", p));
        size.ifPresent(s -> builder.queryParam("size", s));
        sort.ifPresent(s -> builder.queryParam("sort", s));

        String url = builder.build().toUriString();

        ResponseEntity<Person> response = 
        this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, null, Person.class);

        return response.getBody();
    }
```

when i make a request a got this error

```
Raised java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '"code"'
```

Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass `null` as second argument in `getForObject`.
Try it like this:

```
this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, Person.class);
```

More details about how to use HTTP clients in Spring can be found in my German blog:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2021/01/reactive-webclient.html

Comment: thank you for your response, but i have the same error